# Mechanical 5V Relay with High Voltage Trigger

Tags: relay, opto-isolator

I am trying to understand how to make a mechanical relay close with a 5V signal, from an ESP.  Normally I would just try to find a module out there but I am trying to make this relay fit on my PCB.

I found the diagram attached for a relay designed to close on a low voltage signal, but it would be better for my application if the relay was active at high level signal.  Can the circuit below be altered to close the relay at 5V instead of low voltage signal?

http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=2_Channel_5V_Relay_Module#For_raspberry_pi

[image: Mechanical Relay With Low Level Trigger]

Comment: Why not just swap the NC/NO connections of J2 1/3? Relay K2 is "1 form C" relay, when not energized the "Normally Closed (NC)" contacts 1-2 are connected to Common and the "Normally Open (NO)" contacts 1-3 are unconnected from Common. If you've got a different relay, can you use "1 form B" type (Normally Closed) instead of the "1 form A" type (Normally Open)?

Comment: For that matter, since the control signal comes from your Arduino firmware, what is the problem with driving the logic output low? Is there something else sharing the same pin, or is the firmware not under your control?

Comment: I just edited the original post, to ESP from an Arduino, my mistake.  But basically the ESP is connected to a 12V battery and controls the power to a raspberry pi.  The power to the pi must be normally open, because the ESP module has a deep sleep schedule, and powers down most of the board so if the relay was normally closed the pi would be powered while the ESP is sleeping and this is not desired.

Comment: The ESP's 3.3V GPIO is stepped up to 5V to accommodate a 5V relay input signal.  To answer the second comment, I wanted the RPi to only be powered on a 5V signal so there wasn't a chance it would be powered while the ESP was sleeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Ground IN2 to ESP ground, **remove** R4 and connect U2 anode to the ESP GPIO through a 510 ohm resistor.

The ESP is a 3.3V device so a lower resistor value is in order.

Edit: Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNInPA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's possible a lower resistor value would be required to work reliably (or the visible LED may need to be shorted).

Comment: Okay thanks! So disconnect GPIO from opto cathode and connect it to opto anode.  And as you mentioned a 510 resistor would be between the VCC and GPIO?

Comment: See edit. No Vcc

Comment: I see, but I am not sure ESP GPIO can drive this relay.  Max outlet current is about 10mA.  I usually power the ESP's 5V header by an external 5V power source and drive the relay with this same power source.

Comment: It's not driving the relay, it's driving the optoisolator which is driving the transistor which is driving the relay.

Comment: My mistake so VCC is connected where RY-VCC is labeled in the question's diagram?  And this source is still powering the relay.

Comment: Ryvcc and Gnd on your diagram go directly to the power supply for the relay.

Comment: Okay I see, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

> BlockquoteCan the circuit below be altered to close the relay at 5V instead of low voltage signal?

Yes.  Eliminate R4, U2, and the IN2 LED, and use the IN2 signal to drive R3 directly.

Comment: Will the microcontroller still be protected from the high voltage circuit?

Comment: Also GPIO can only output 10mA this will not be enough to drive relay.

Comment: The GPIO does not drive the relay.  It drives the transistor that drives the relay.